# Newtonsoft JsonConverter to convert a string or object to object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a requirement for some deserialization I'm trying to handle where I could have these potential inputs:

```
{
    "value": "a string"
}
```

-- or --

```
{
    "value": {
        "text": "a string"
        // there are other properties, but for successful deserialization I only need text present
    }
}
```

And I expect it to be able to successfully convert to the object, `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("text")
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

So far this is what I have in my converter.  This case works fine when it's a string (although not very efficient because I'm throwing an exception to catch a failed deserialization).  However, when it's an object the reader throws an exception  and I'm uncertain of how to handle it.

```
public class MyObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get => false; }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string) || objectType == typeof(MyObject);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = reader.Value?.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            return JObject.Parse(value).ToObject<MyObject>();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new MyObject
            {
                Text = value
            };
        }
    }
}
```

perhaps I'm there is already a nice way to do this that I'm unaware of?  If not, how can I determine whether my input is a string or an object to be able to return the object  I care about?

SOLUTION:

```
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            return new MyObject
            {
                Text = reader.Value?.ToString()
            };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            return obj.ToObject<MyObject>();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have two completely different models that you are trying to shoe-horn in to one model. Why not just create two different models? It will increase the life cycle of your code. Right now you are tightly coupling a complex routine to cover a scenario that could be solved by doing things in a simpler, easer to read and maintain manner.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the whole JSON as shown into a `MyObject` instance, or are you trying to convert just the `value` to a `MyObject` instance (so `MyObject` would be a property of an outer object which isn't otherwise shown in your question)?

Comment: @Andy, it's gross, I know.  Another team changed up a schema and we're forced to adapt to continue work.  If I made the change to the object it will break other services so this is a temporary hack until we can properly address the change.

Comment: I love that when that happens. Well, the answer below gets you were you need to be. Hopefully it all works out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Object isn't structured like the input your expecting.  For the second case, MyObject would need to look like this:

```
// this is ugly
public class MyObject
{
    public Value value{get;set;}

    public class Value{
         public string text {get;set;}
    }
}
```

If you want to have just an object with a single Text property like you currently do, you could do something like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object 
    existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
    var value = obj["value"];

    if(value is JObject)  // this will be true if the value property is a nested structure
       return new MyObject(){Text=value["text"]};  // could also do value.ToObject<MyObject>() if you need more properties
    else
       return new MyObject(){Text=value};
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but how is he going to know which one is the right value that was used? He wants both data structures to point at a very specific model. You created a new model.

Comment: Nevermind -- i re-read your code/upvoted. It's how it should be. Sorry about that.

Comment: This got me on the right path.  I needed to do a check at the beginning to see if the reader's value was a string or a "StartObject".  From there I could branch off and do the proper translations.  I'll post my solution in my answer.  Thank you for the help!